# send variables in json in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I am trying to send 2 variables from php using json which carries HTML TABLE TR with TD in AJAX.

```
    public function actionAllowancelist(){
    $Role = UserController::CheckRole("payroll");
     if($Role == true){
        try {
            $query = new Query();
            $allowances = $query->select(['PayrollSettingID', 'IsAllowance','Title','Amount','Formula'])->from('payrollsetting')->where(['IsActive'=>1])->all();
            $allow=NULL;
            $dedu=NULL;
            if($allowances != NULL && sizeof($allowances) > 0){
                foreach ($allowances as $allowance){
                    if($allowance['IsAllowance'] == 0){
                        $allow .='<tr data-id="">';
                            $allow.='<td>'.$allowance['Title'].'</td>';
                            if ($allowance['Formula'] != NULL) {
                                $allow.='<td>'.$allowance['Amount'].'</td>';
                                $allow.='<td hidden="true">'.$allowance['Formula'].'</td>';
                            }else{
                                $allow.='<td contenteditable = "true">'.$allowance['Amount'].'</td>';
                                $allow.='<td hidden="true">'.$allowance['Formula'].'</td>';
                            }
                            $allow .='</tr>';
                         }else{
                            $dedu .='<tr data-id="">';
                            $dedu.='<td>'.$allowance['Title'].'</td>';
                            if ($allowance['Formula'] != NULL) {
                                $dedu.='<td>'.$allowance['Amount'].'</td>';
                                $dedu.='<td hidden="true">'.$allowance['Formula'].'</td>';
                            }else{
                                $dedu.='<td contenteditable = "true">'.$allowance['Amount'].'</td>';
                                $dedu.='<td hidden="true">'.$allowance['Formula'].'</td>';
                            }
                            $dedu .='</tr>';
                         }
                    }
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
        return '{"allowance":'.$allow',"deduction":'.$dedu.'}';
     }


}//function ends here
```

In Ajax at frontend i am just trying to grab these values and the dataType is JSON.
How can i get these table TD in the the frontend to populate in the tables?

Comment: Why aren't you using [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)?

Comment: added an answer for you see if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Because by default the response format is HTML, you should only return a string in an action method. If you want to use a different response format, you should set it first before returning the data. For example,

```
public function actionInfo()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return [
        'message' => 'hello world',
        'code' => 100,
    ];
}
```

Now looking at your code you are not `encoding` the `response` and you are not returning the `exception` message in the response, you should add a `msg` index to the response array and then check it on the `js` side if empty them use the `deduction` and `allowance` html and if not empty then alert the `msg` so that the error/exception is displayed.

```
 public function actionAllowancelist() {
    $Role = UserController::CheckRole ( "payroll" );

    $msg = '';

    if ( $Role == true ) {
        try {
            $query = new Query();
            $allowances = $query->select ( [ 'PayrollSettingID' , 'IsAllowance' , 'Title' , 'Amount' , 'Formula' ] )->from ( 'payrollsetting' )->where ( [ 'IsActive' => 1 ] )->all ();
            $allow = NULL;
            $dedu = NULL;
            if ( $allowances != NULL && sizeof ( $allowances ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( $allowances as $allowance ) {
                    if ( $allowance['IsAllowance'] == 0 ) {
                        $allow .= '<tr data-id="">';
                        $allow .= '<td>' . $allowance['Title'] . '</td>';
                        if ( $allowance['Formula'] != NULL ) {
                            $allow .= '<td>' . $allowance['Amount'] . '</td>';
                            $allow .= '<td hidden="true">' . $allowance['Formula'] . '</td>';
                        } else {
                            $allow .= '<td contenteditable = "true">' . $allowance['Amount'] . '</td>';
                            $allow .= '<td hidden="true">' . $allowance['Formula'] . '</td>';
                        }
                        $allow .= '</tr>';
                    } else {
                        $dedu .= '<tr data-id="">';
                        $dedu .= '<td>' . $allowance['Title'] . '</td>';
                        if ( $allowance['Formula'] != NULL ) {
                            $dedu .= '<td>' . $allowance['Amount'] . '</td>';
                            $dedu .= '<td hidden="true">' . $allowance['Formula'] . '</td>';
                        } else {
                            $dedu .= '<td contenteditable = "true">' . $allowance['Amount'] . '</td>';
                            $dedu .= '<td hidden="true">' . $allowance['Formula'] . '</td>';
                        }
                        $dedu .= '</tr>';
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            $msg = $e->getMessage ();
        }

        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return [
            'msg' => $msg ,
            'allowance' => $allow ,
            'deduction' => $dedu
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad Omer Aslam.

Comment: you are welcome @Alesh do select the answer if it worked for you

Comment: yes the problem is during returning the value i corrected and it worked fine.

Comment: so you are trying to say due to some correction you did you are not selecting it as correct ? @Alesh and what was that correction

Comment: Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return [
            'msg' => $msg ,
            'allowance' => $allow ,
            'deduction' => $dedu
        ];

Comment: what is the correction in these lines that YOU did, it is already there and i dont find this reason strong enough to not select the answer although it helped you out, any way take care i would be careful next time posting an answer.